# Маршрутизируемые события

Tags: wpf

Начал изучать WPF с книги Макдональда и столкнулся с непониманием практического предназначения маршрутизируемых событий.

Может кто-нибудь привести практический пример, когда они используются? 
Верно ли, что эти события используются только при написании своих контролов?

Comment: Еще эти события присутствуют практически во всех элементах UIElement, а не только в контролах. Поскольку они имеют механизм всплывания и тунелирования, то надо понимать принцип их работы. В противном случае можно наткнуться на довольно странные поведения программы. Так же особенности можно использовать при обработке событий в других местах, типичный пример, перехват горячих клавиш.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Практический пример: меня не устраивала обычная скорость прокрутки `ScrollViewer`а, в силу чего я увеличил скорость прокрутки в 30 раз:

```
<ScrollViewer PreviewMouseWheel="ScrollViewer_OnPreviewMouseWheel">
```

И обработчик:

```
private void ScrollViewer_OnPreviewMouseWheel(object sender, MouseWheelEventArgs e)
{
    var scrollViewer = sender as ScrollViewer;
    if (scrollViewer != null)
    {
        scrollViewer.ScrollToVerticalOffset(scrollViewer.VerticalOffset + (30 * (e.Delta > 0 ? -1 : 1)));
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

Что произошло (простыми словами): я перехватил маршрутизируемое событие колесика мышки `PreviewMouseWheel` **до того**, как это событие "провалилось" дальше (и попало бы в обработчик непосредственно `ScrollViewer`, который выполнил бы прокрутку с обычной скоростью). Затем я просто вручную осуществил прокрутку скрола (с помощью `ScrollToVerticalOffset`) на величину прокрутки, увеличенную в 30 раз.

Поскольку прокрутка по факту уже сделана, мне не нужно чтобы событие "проваливалось" дальше (что приведет к вызову прокрутки по умолчанию на стороне скрола), поэтому я *использую возможности маршрутизируемого события* и запрещаю ему "проваливаться" дальше путем установки `e.Handled = true`.

Касательно второго вопроса - не совсем понял. Вы можете использовать маршрутизируемые события уже существующих контролов, равно как и создавать произвольные маршрутизируемые события для своих контролов.